# Push an variable into a method

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an httpWebRequest to access an XML and save it locally then read it and show it to the screen. Problem is, i have to do this for more than one "pivot item", and the method that saves the xml is

```
private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
```

and doesn't support adding a new variable to it so i can dynamically name the xml ("tmp"+xmlName+".xml") .

So the question is: **How do i push a variable in the xml name ?**

```
public class HttpWebReqMethod
    {

        public void httpRequestMethod (string url, string xmlName)
        {     
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";

            httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), httpRequest);
        }

        private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation
            Stream postStream = httpRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);


            string postData = "";

            // Convert the string into a byte array.
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Write to the request stream.
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
            httpRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), httpRequest);
        }

        private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseStream = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var istream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(@"tmp" + xmlName + ".xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store))
                {
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(istream))
                    {
                        sw.Write(responseStream);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Close the stream object
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();

            // Release the HttpWebResponse
            response.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things you could do:

1. make GetResponseCallback not static, and **store the xmlName in an instance variable**
2. pass a **state object** (anything that has a property named xmlName, and something else to identify it by) to the request, and you can get it from the `AsyncState`
3. change GetResponseCallback's function to the following, and make the **whole thing a callback "factory"**

   ```
   private static AsyncCallback GetResponseCallback(string xmlName)
    {
       return (IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) =>{
       HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
       // End the operation
       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
       Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
       StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
       string responseStream = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

       using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
       {
           using (var istream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(@"tmp" + xmlName + ".xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store))
           {
               using (var sw = new StreamWriter(istream))
               {
                   sw.Write(responseStream);
               }
           }
       }

       // Close the stream object
       streamResponse.Close();
       streamRead.Close();

       // Release the HttpWebResponse
       response.Close();
     }
   }
   ```

EDIT to ADD:
the usage then changes to

```
 httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback(xmlName), httpRequest);
```

Comment: Oh I see rudi_visser chose the second option and explained it much better :) Still the third is a good one and for certain scenarios can be very useful.

Comment: could you help me whith the "callback" factory? I am getting: GetResponseCallback(string)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: that answer did it. I just needed to clear my head a little :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a callback method which is mapped to a specific delegate type, so no, you can't amend it's signature.

One option to resolve this would be to have a separate class such as this:

```
class HttpRequestState {
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest;
    string xmlFileName;
}
```

You can then set an instance of that class as the state object when you run the Begin callback:

`httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), httpRequest);`

would change to

`httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), new HttpRequestState() { httpWebRequest = httpRequest; xmlFileName = "tmp"+xmlName+".xml" });`

Then of course, you can pull out the xmlFileName *and* the httpWebRequest like this:

```
HttpRequestState stateObj = (HttpRequestState)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = stateObj.httpWebRequest;
string fileName = xmlFileName;
```